# Apache POI ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I am using eclipse to try and get a list of sheets from an excel spreadsheet but when I go to run it Java throws exceptions.

here is the code;

```
File myFile = new File("excel.xlsx");
    Workbook wb = null;
    try {
        wb = WorkbookFactory.create(myFile);
    } catch (EncryptedDocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<String> sheetNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
        sheetNames.add( wb.getSheetName(i) );
    }
    System.out.println(sheetNames);
```

here is the log;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:252)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:231)
    at com.cogentautomation.view.View.main(View.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

I have included the following in the eclipse java build path as libraries;

- commons-codec
- commons-logging
- junit
- log4j
- poi
- poi-ooxml
- poi-scratchpad

I know the solution is something simple but my mind is blanking. I am not using maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to add XMLBeans dependency.You can include the dependency from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.6.0

Answer (score 2):

As the exception message is telling you, you need the [XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/) library. Poi probably depends on it.

If you were using a dependency management tool such as Gradle or Maven, it would have automatically been included.